# Setting state in component vs setting state in a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

### The crux of the issue

I'm not able to understand why setting a recoil state in a component has a different behaviour than setting it in a hook.

### The details of the issue

Our codebase had a component which looked somewhat like this

```
const ComponentThatReturnsNothing = () => {
    const [, setSomeRecoilState] = useRecoilState(someStateAtom);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.Bridge = {
            // the following function is called by Android, as the code runs inside a webview
            functionThatSetsRecoilState: () => setSomeRecoilState('A_VALUE');
        }
    }, []);

    return null;
}
```

However, I did not like the fact that there was a component with pure logic inside it, which never returned anything, so I converted it into a hook instead. The hook looks the same, except that it has a different name according to hook conventions, and is called at the top of the `App` component, instead of inside the `render` of `App`.

This brought about an interesting problem, which I haven't been able to figure out the cause of.

So the recoil state is actually used in a component named `SMSSender` like this:

```
const SMSSender = () => {
    const [someRecoilState] = useSomeRecoilState(someStateAtom);
    
    return (
        someRecoilState === 'B_VALUE'
        ? <FirstChild />
        : <SecondChild />
    );
}
```

Furthermore, the `SMSSender` is being used in another called `CustomerInitiate`. So the component tree looks like this:

```
.
└── App
    ├── ComponentThatReturnsNothing
    └── CustomerInitiate
        └── SMSSender
```

`CustomerInitiate` looks somewhat like this:

```
const CustomerInitiate = () => {
    const isConditionTrue = AndroidInterface.androidMethod(); // returns false before we set the recoil state, returns true afterwards

    return (
        isConditionTrue ? <UnrelatedComponent /> : <SMSSender />
    );
}
```

#### Important thing to know

At the point of time where `functionThatSetsRecoilState` is called by Android, we are rendering `SMSSender`. However, after it is called, `androidMethod()` starts returning `true`, which means the next time `CustomerInitiate` re-renders, we change screens.

#### The difference between behaviour in component vs hook

When `ComponentThatReturnsNothing` was a component, we could successfully render `SecondChild` in `SMSSender` after the recoil state was set to `A_VALUE`. `SecondChild` makes an API call which we need to happen before `CustomerInitiate` changes screens.

However, after changing `ComponentThatReturnsNothing` to a hook, `CustomerInitiate` starts rendering `UnrelatedComponent` before `SecondChild` can be called and the API call made. Since `UnrelatedComponent` makes another API that counts on `SecondChild`'s API call being made first, this is an issue.

#### My guess

My current guess is that if a child component of `App` is subscribed to a recoil state that changes, it doesn't re-render the whole `App` component, which means that `CustomerInitiate` isn't re-rendered immediately.

However, if a hook inside the `App` component is subscribed to a recoil state which changes, it is re-rendering the whole `App` component, causing `CustomerInitiate` to re-render and not giving a chance to the `SMSSender` to render `SecondChild`.

#### Update

I solved the problem by moving the `SecondChild` up to `CustomerInitiate` along with the check required to render it, however, answers regarding why this problem occurred in the first place and whether or not my guess is correct are still welcome.